# Check which other scripts were used when I run some script

Tags: python, spyder

I want to tease out exactly which scripts were used when I run a certain script in a repository (through importing some modules from those script etc.). I think stepping through is too tedious as there any a few hundreds of lines of code in the script I run. I am using Spyder IDE 5. Is there any built-in feature allows me to do that?

Comment: Try searching for `python dependency tree for script`. You'll get some results about mapping `pip` dependencies, but there are some relevant results there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a Code Analysis feature in Spyder.

Comment: @RifloSnake yes I saw it. But how to use it to see which modules are imported from which script?